# Environment Variable filtering

Tags: shell

Where does the filtering of environment variables occur? for instance, say you are using LD_PRELOAD for shared library interposition. However, when a setuid program is run, the LD_PRELOAD variable has no effect. It represents a case of what I am dubbing "environment variable filtering." I was wondering where the processing and 'purging' of environment variables takes place, specifically and/or precisely.

Comment: There's plenty of examples out there (google)

Comment: please point me in the right direction. I did not find anything.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426230/what-is-the-ld-preload-trick

Comment: Nope, I am looking for environment variable filtering. That link is all about LD_PRELOAD and how it is a library interposer over shared libraries. My question is, where does the filtering of environment variables occur? My question only used LD_PRELOAD as an example because, for instance, when an setuid program is run, the LD_PRELOAD variable will not work. It represents a case of this environment variable filtering, or nullification. I was wondering where on the OS level the processing and 'purging' of environment variables takes place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dynamic loader deals with `LD_PRELOAD` and related environment variables.  It also determines whether a program is running SUID and ignores the environment variables.

The actual name and location of the dynamic loader varies by system.  For example, on RHEL 5 for x86/64, the library is `/lib/ld-linux.so.2` for 32-bit software and `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` for 64-bit software; on Solaris 10 for SPARC, there's `/lib/ld.so.1` for 32-bit code, and `/lib/sparcv9/ld.so.1` for 64-bit code.